# jQuery Dialog Bizarre Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, oop

This is by far the most annoying and bizarre issue I have ever encountered with jQuery.  It is ridiculously basic (one of those Murphy's Law bugs)

I have a div (divDialog):

```
    <div id="divDialog">
    </div>
```

I call the dialog function:

```
    $('#divDialog').dialog();
```

It gives me this error in firebug:

```
    this.element[0].nodetitle is undefined
```

If I remove the div, the error disappears.  If I console out just the selector portion,
it shows the node in firebug and all looks well.  I am currently extending jquery in the following ways:

```
$.fn.isAfter = function(sel){ //returns true if element is after, else return false, for animations
    return this.prevAll(sel).length > 0;
}
$.fn.isBefore= function(sel){ //returns true if element is before, else return false, for animations
    return this.nextAll(sel).length > 0;
}
$.fn.exists = function(){ //returns true if element exists, false if not
    return this.length>0;
}
$.fn.btnClick = function(fn){ //check if the element is disabled before executing onclick
    $(this).click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('disabled')!='disabled'){
            fn(this);
        }
    });
    return $(this);
}
$.fn.btnToggle = function(){ //toggle disable/enable
    if($(this).attr('disabled')=='disabled'){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    return $(this);
}
```

I am also extending the Array prototype:

```
    Array.prototype.isArray = true; //this allows us to say if(variable.isArray) to detect arrays
```

Any ideas?  I am beyond frustrated with this.  Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it happening in Chrome or IE?

Comment: stack trace for the error? Is tracing viable?

Comment: What version of jQuery-ui are you using?  I can't find any reference to 'nodetitle' in the latest version at: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js

Comment: nor does the jQuery 1.7.1 source code refer to 'nodetitle'

Comment: Not part of your question, but I would also recommend that instead of extending Array.prototype like that, just use `x instanceof Array`

Comment: @Waxen doesn't work when dealing with objects from different frames. On the other hand, neither does this.

Comment: Hold on, let me try the latest from google's service.  Thank you for the quick replies.  I'll post what I find here shortly.  Its firefox specific.  I haven't tested in IE or Chrome, but then again those two are almost more finicky than Firefox.

Comment: Yes, it was outdate jquery.  Let me post the version that I was using for future reference...  jQuery version 1.7.1,  UI version 1.8.10

Comment: It looks like it was the UI Library.  Node Title does occur in that, and dialog isn't a native jquery function.  It's part of the UI package.  Just FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was apparently a version issue with jQuery, jQuery UI, or the pairing of them.  I was using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.1.  The problem disappeared upon using that AJAX libs from google.  Nodetitle only occurs within the UI lib, so I am assuming the big lies somewhere in there.  To any jQuery devs, I would suggest some sort of package control between UI and vanilla.  Perhaps UI could be ported into the browser by using an AJAX call so that UI always matches up with the proper vanilla package?  Anyway, resolved.